# GCP Composer monitoring shows that task queue is always empty

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm new to Airflow and also Composer on GCP. I found that the GCP provided metric `composer.googleapis.com/environment/task_queue_length` is always 0 while we do have huge gap (~1 min) between tasks. Any suggestions why? Or maybe I misunderstood something?

Comment: Tasks will not be queued unless you configure concurrency or parallelism limits that warrant that behavior - even in overload situations. Could you review your worker nodes' resource utilizations to see if any might be overloaded?

Comment: @hexacyanide thanks for replying. From what I see, CPU is usually between 20%-40%, while memory is more bursty. The reason I'm not so sure is the metrics on Composer page and on GKE page are different, I take that the GKE ones are more accurate.
We didn't overwrite any parallelism or concurrency, but from what I read Composer set those values by default, doesn't it? I do see tasks go to "queued" state though.

Comment: Do you have many tasks? How is the scheduling of your DAG?